# Как вставить на страницу часть другой html-страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, вёрстка

Ситуация: на HTML-страницу нужно вставить один или несколько фрагментов с другой страницы. Нашел js, который позволяет вставить страницу целиком, но мне нужно вставить только фрагмент, например, поместить в DIVы нужный фрагмент и с помощью js-запроса отображать только содержимое этих DIVов. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test </title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="external_page1">
        <!-- here goes the content of the external_page1 -->

    </div>
    <div id="external_page2">
        <!-- here goes the content of the external_page2 -->

    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get('external_page1.html',function(data){ $('#external_page1').html(data);});
        $.get('external_page2.html',function(data){$('#external_page2').html(data);});

        // you can also use $.post method instead of $.get 

        // $.post('external_page1.html',function(data){ $('#external_page1').html(data);});
        // $.post('external_page1.html',function(data){$('#external_page2').html(data);});

    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

пример
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments Существует уже лет 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как то так можно сделать

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="external_page1">
        <!-- here goes the content of the external_page1 -->

    </div>
    <div id="external_page2">
        <!-- here goes the content of the external_page2 -->

    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get('external_page1.html',function(data){
          //data - полученные данные
          let div = document.createElement('div');
          // div - контейнер, для данных
          div.innerHTML = data;

          
          let $div = $(div);
          // ищем в контейнере нужный элемент
          let find_el = $div.find('.some_class');

          // если искомый элкмент найден вставляем его
          if(find_el)
            $('#external_page1').append(find_el);
        });        
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: не получилось(  

`<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get('http://www.site.ru/p/page.html',function(data){
          let div = document.createElement('aaa1');
          div.innerHTML = data;

          let $div = $(div);
          $('#http://www.site.ru/p/page.html').append(
            $div.find('aaa1')
          );
        });        
    });

</script>


    <div id="aaa1">

    </div> 
`

Comment: @koiem038 что это? - $('#http://www.site.ru/p/page.html').append...

Comment: ну,как в примере
`let $div = $(div);
          $('#external_page1').append((`

-----
то есть ссылка на страницу, с которой я хочу взять фрагмент, и где этот фрагмент оборачиваю в DIV, выглядит примерно так: http://www.site.ru/p/page.html

Или я весь код неправильно написал?)

Comment: @koiem038 дополнил ответ комментариями. Вместо этого`$('#http://www.site.ru/p/page.html')` должен быть селектор элемента куда будет происходить вставка

Comment: чёт никак( 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SdV7.jpg
я добавил в пост скрин - как выглядит код на странице

Comment: @koiem038 во первых вот так `if(find_el) $('.aaa1').append(find_el);`. `$div.find('.some_class');` - где '.some_class' надо заменить на искомый элемент в странице которая получена с сервера

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо! Работает)

Answer (score 0):

Лучше это делать на сервере, испольpуя include.

Comment: к сожалению, нет такой возможности - это сайт на платформе blogger.com